# Pycharm: "unresolved reference" error on the IDE when opening a working project

Tags: python, pycharm

**Intro**

I have a Python project on a git repository. Everything works ok for most of the team members, we can sync the code and edit it without any problem with Pycharm on different platforms (Windows, Linux)

**The problem**

On one of the computers we are getting "Unresolved reference" all over the code on almost every import with the exception of Python's built in libraries (i.e. import datetime is working). This computer is running the Mac version of Pycharm.

**The question**

Anyone knows how to solve this?, since most of the imports are not recognized code completion and navigation trough goto->declaration and so on is not working. Is there any known issue with the Mac version?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The key is to mark your source directory as a source root. Try the following:

- In the Project view, right-click on the Python source directory
- In the dialog menu select **Mark Directory As** > **Source Root**

The folder should now appear blue instead of beige, to indicate it is a Python source folder.

You can also configure this in PyCharm preferences by doing the following for a project that is already in PyCharm:

- In the Mac toolbar, select **PyCharm** > **Preferences**
- In the window that opens, select **Project Structure** from the menu pane on the left
- Select your project in the middle pane, if necessary
- Right-click on your Python source in the right pane and select **Sources** from the menu dialog

Comment: Then restart the IDE... - oops not even this worked. Why can't people write an IDE that works, _why_ ?

Comment: You should;  " File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart " it worked for me. @Mr_and_Mrs_D

Comment: @myildirim: thanks - will check this if I ever go back

Comment: i still have the same problem... it happens mostly with third party apps

Comment: Invalidate Caches / Restart fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Just be aware that you can only add one `Content Root` but you can add several `Source Folders`.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the problem, and it took me few hours to find the exact solution.

You need to confirm the following things.

1. `'django.contrib.staticfiles'`, is added to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the `settings.py` file of your application.
2. The directory with the static contents (for example, images), named `static`, resides under the application root.

### Now Do the following

PyCharm > Preferences > Project Settings > Django

Make sure your `Django Project root`, `Settings.py` and `manage.py` script are well defined in the dialog box.

You are good to go. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately in my case it wasn't a django project so this method doesn't apply. Probably it will help others as an alternative tho.

Comment: Cool, Thanks, Rock and Roll!!

Comment: @Clayton How does entire settings.py file look like ? What exactly you changed ?

Answer (score 3):

I did all the stuff above from einnocent and myildirim but still had to do the following:

close pycharm and manually delete the .idea folder, this deletes everything pycharm knows about the code.

open pycharm, reimport the project

the combination of setting the correct source root, restarting python with invaliding cache and deleting the .idea folder / reimporting the pycharm project fixed it for me.

Comment: i wanted to add that to the answer of einnocent since it would have fit there really well. without the reputation to comment, i posted it as a seperate answer.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Seems like a perfectly reasonable answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same issue 8 years after the original question. And manually deleting the `.idea/` folder and remarking the source folders works. But there is still no better solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue with pyspark ( spark 2.1 ) & luigi.

**Failed tries:**

1. Setting PYTHONPATH environment variable
2. Invalidate cache & restart pycharm
3. Mark directory as **Source Root**

**Unresolved reference `pyspark`** could be fixed by adding the spark's python directory as **Content Root** in the project, but running the project as luigi task gave the same error.

**Successfull steps**

- Create an empty `__init__.py` file in the project
- Include following lines of code at the top of script

  ```
  ...
  import sys

  sys.path.append("/path/to/spark/python")

  sys.path.append("/path/to/spark/python/lib")

  ...
  // import pyspark files after above mentioned lines
  ```

and the Unresolved reference error issue was fixed both in pycharm & luigi task.

Answer (score 1):

My ten-penneth - If you're working with virtual environments (have a `venv` directory) make sure it is marked as excluded.

Plagiarised from above:

- In the Project view, right-click on the `venv` directory
- In the dialog menu select **Mark Directory As** > **Excluded**

The directory should turn orange...

This sometimes happens if you've done a `git clean` or for whatever reason had to rebuild your environment and PyCharm hasn't *noticed*

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm > select "File" menu > select "Invalidate Caches / Restart" menu option

Answer (score 0):

The other reason may be *project interpreter*. For example, if you are using Python3.x, but the interpreter is for Python2.x You can check here:

> File | Settings | Project: 'projectname' | Project Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm - Alt-F(ile); Settings; **Project Structure**; click **+Add content root**; 
point your folder containing the package in contention: /home/joker/anaconda3/envs/conda_py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages.
I additionally marked as resources (not sure if this is mandatory). Click ok and the reindexing happens. 
This **solved** the problem for me in **PyCharm Professional 2016.2.3**

Comment: I tried to do that. But it says that content roots shouldn't intersect. Doesn't allow it to add the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem with OpenCV and none of these answers worked.

The only solution that did was adding the OpenCV folder path to the interpreter.
This solution explains all the steps: [This Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44659906/pycharm-opencv-autocomplete-with-import-cv2-cv2-no-errors-with-import-cv2/69849595#69849595)