# pycharm cannot find reference 'layer' in '__init__.py' for cocos2d

Tags: python, python-3.x, cocos2d-python

I am just starting out to learn `cocos2d` using python.

When I write this in pycharm :

```
import cocos

class HelloWorld(cocos.layer.Layer):
def __init__(self):
    super(HelloWorld, self).__init__()
    label = cocos.text.Label('Hello, World!',
                             font_name = 'Times New Roman',
                             font_size = 32,
                             anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center')
    label.position = 320, 240
    self.add(label)
cocos.director.director.init()
hello_layer = HelloWorld()
main_scene = cocos.scene.Scene(hello_layer)
cocos.director.director.run(main_scene)
```

Pycharm shows the error `cannot find reference 'layer' in '__init__.py'` but when I run it, the code works. The code works even when run from inside pycharm (not via terminal), although I don't find it surprising, but thought maybe it requires mentioning.
It also doesn't gives any auto-suggestions and/or auto-completes anything related to `cocos2d`.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

I am using python 3.4.

Comment: It could be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py-python-pycharm?rq=1) issue, about a bug in PyCharm