# PyCharm: specifying type of returned variable?

Tags: python, oop, autocomplete, pycharm

How do I make PyCharm understand completions for a returned variable?

As per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/5.0/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html

I'm asserting the type of a variable, but not getting any completions.

```
import boto.kinesis
x = boto.kinesis.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
assert isinstance(x, boto.kinesis.layer1.KinesisConnection)

foo = x.    <--- not getting completions here
```

[image]

Python 2,7, PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to [Cannot find reference 'xxx' in __init__.py - Python / Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py-python-pycharm/23839976#23839976) and the fact that there is no `__all__` defined inside the [`__init__.py` inside the `boto.kinesis` package](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/kinesis/__init__.py).

Importing the `KinesisConnection` directly from `boto.kinesis.layer1` made it work for me:

```
import boto.kinesis
from boto.kinesis.layer1 import KinesisConnection

x = boto.kinesis.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
assert isinstance(x, KinesisConnection)
```

[image]

---

You can also import it and add a `type` hint into the comments:

```
import boto.kinesis
from boto.kinesis.layer1 import KinesisConnection

x = boto.kinesis.connect_to_region("us-west-2")  # type: KinesisConnection
```

[image]

Comment: Both of those worked, thanks.  I'm filing an enhancement request with JetBrains to eliminate the need for the extra import.

Comment: @MarkHarrison I suspect they would refer to the way the `boto.kinesis` package is structured/defined since `layer1` is not explicitly listed inside `__all__`, looks related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py-python-pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

**(PyCharm Developer replies, via JetBrains support)**

As @alexce noted the underlying problem is that PyCharm fails to resolve `boto.kinesis.layer1` reference and hence symbol to `boto.kinesis.layer1.KinesisConnection` can't be resolved too.

Normally you can't refer to submodules of a package this way (without importing them explicitly). If PyCharm allowed it, there would be tons of false negative errors when one forgets to add necessary import statement. But because situations like that are quite common, we look through `boto/kinesis/__init__.py` trying to find some indication that `sys.modules['boto.kinesis']` might already contain the attribute `layer1`.

Anything of the following would do:

```
from boto.kinesis import layer1
from . import layer1
from boto.kinesis.layer1 import KinesisConnection
import boto.kinesis.layer1
'layer1' in __all__
```

In fact `__init__.py` indeed contains the third of these import statements, but inside a function:

```
def regions():
    ...
    from boto.kinesis.layer1 import KinesisConnection
    ...
```

Since we can't guarantee statically that this function is called at runtime, we have nothing more to do other than warn about the unresolved reference in the editor.