# checking TensorFlow version in Python - "tf.__version__" vs "tf.VERSION"?

Tags: python, tensorflow

***Shortest possible version of question:***

When checking TensorFlow version in Python, can somebody explain/clarify the difference between `tf.__version__` and `tf.VERSION` ??

***Slightly longer version of question:***

This seems to work:

```
if tf.__version__ < "1.8.0":
    print("ERROR: currently running TensorFlow version " + tf.__version__ + ", at least version 1.8.0 is required")
    return
# end if
```

This also seems to work:

```
if tf.VERSION < "1.8.0":
    print("ERROR: currently running TensorFlow version " + tf.VERSION + ", at least version 1.8.0 is required")
    return
# end if
```

One difference I have noticed is that the editor PyCharm shows a warning for the `tf.__version__` way but does not for the tf.VERSION way:

[image]

A work around for this in PyCharm is to add the `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` comment above each `tf.__version__` useage, which resolved the warning:

[image]

However the `tf.VERSION` way does not show a warning in PyCharm without the `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` comment:

[image]

I asked about the PyCharm `tf.__version__` warning in this post:

[TensorFlow Python warning in PyCharm - Cannot find reference __version__ in __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368096/tensorflow-python-warning-in-pycharm-cannot-find-reference-version-in-in)

and the only responder stated that `tf.__version__` is generated dynamically.  In the context of Python specifically I don't really understand what this means.

So at this point I have the following questions:

1) Why do both of these exist?

2) Is one generally recommended over the other?

3) Why does PyCharm show a warning for one but not the other?

4) What does it mean that `tf.__version__` is generated dynamically?  How is `tf.VERSION` generated if a different way?

5) To avoid having to add the `# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences` comment I'd prefer to use `tf.VERSION`, is there any reason not to do this?

6) Most of the examples within the TensorFlow repository https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow and the related repositories (ex. models https://github.com/tensorflow/models) use the `tf.__version__` way but some use the `tf.VERSION` way, is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Shortest possible version of the answer

They are the same.

### "Slightly" longer version of the answer

Both symbols are aliases of `tensorflow.python.framework.versions.VERSION` and are imported in the file `tools\api\generator\api\__init__.py` as

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.versions import VERSION
from tensorflow.python.framework.versions import VERSION as __version__
```

Going down the rabbit hole, the aliases eventually point to the `__version__` of `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal`, which is basically tensorflow's C++ library which is indeed loaded dynamically -- in the end, python's `__version__` is just an alias of [`TF_VERSION_STRING`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.8.0/tensorflow/core/public/version.h#L33) of the C++ API.

Now why would PyCharm emit a warning for the second, it could be a limitation (a bug?) of PyCharm's parsing that cannot cope with complex definitions of `__all__` as the one defined at the end of the same file. Search for "PyCharm `__all__`" on this site and you will find some hints of that.

So in the particular case of `tensorflow`, both options should be fine, and you could use `tf.VERSION` if it removes a warning for you. However the `__version__` idiom is more common (some would say standard) because it is a recommandation of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#module-level-dunder-names), so I would possibly stick to `tf.__version__`.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 2.0 RC, `VERSION` seems to be gone:

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
2.0.0-rc0
>>> print(tf.VERSION)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'VERSION'
>>>
```

Comment: Run `tf.version.VERSION` instead. The API is still there :) The code has been refactored to you can't find it. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/version