# matplotlib versions 2.2.0 returns error in plt.show

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot but I face some errors

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
x = np.arange(0, 3 * np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

what is its problem?

> cannot find reference 'arange' in __ init__.py
>   I'm using pycharm on windows 10

is there any difference between `matplotlib.py` and `matplotlib.pyplot`?
I can not find the second one

solved: use version 2.1.2

Comment: well your code works fine. what errors are you facing ? kindly edit your post/question and post errors to.

Comment: it seems it cannot import matplotlib, but I've already installed it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find reference 'xxx' in \_\_init\_\_.py - Python / Pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py-python-pycharm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with my version of matplotlib
I've installed v.2.2.0. uninstalled it and installed v.2.1.2 then this code start working.

Answer (score 0):

Well first check the versions of your `numpy` and `matplotlib` libraries and your code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0, 3 * np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

works fine..
It gives me output like this:

[image]

So, maybe the problem is with your versions, Moreover, It seems that your `numpy package` is not installed correctly according to your error. install numpy package and then again run your code.
also add `matplotlib.pyplot` instead or only `matplotlib`

Also check this: [Matplotlib, Pylab, Pyplot, etc: What's the difference between these and when to use each?](http://queirozf.com/entries/matplotlib-pylab-pyplot-etc-what-s-the-different-between-these)

Hope this will help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your import of matplotlib is not correct.
Use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` (notice the extra `.pyplot` in there)

It'll should run properly.