# "Cannot find reference" when import from Keras

Tags: python, keras, pycharm

Following this example to start https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/

```
# first neural network with keras tutorial
from numpy import loadtxt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

Installed numpy and keras, numpy is ok, but there are red lines under "Sequential" and "Dense".

[image]

Here's the Error messages:

Cannot find reference 'Sequential' in 'models.py'

Cannot find reference 'Dense' in '**init**.py'

[image]

Wonder how I can fix this? I had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py-python-pycharm) but think it might be a different problem?

Also, on a completely different note, I can not install tensorflow for some reason? ...

[image]

Comment: You are probably using a MacBook M1. In that case use the package `tensorflow-macos`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of October 2020 Tensorflow only supports the 64-bit version of Python and Tensorflow only supports Python 3.5 to 3.8.

Update your project in PyCharm to run Python 64-bit and this should solve your problem.

Comment: ok so I am using python 3.9 64x, guess i need to downgrade my python?

Comment: @sotonLoon Try downgrading to 3.8, you can change your project interpreter by pressing `"ctrl + alt + s"` and then adjusting the environment, you can always experiment by creating your own virtual environment and adding selected packages and Python versions too.

Comment: can confirm running perfectly after installing tensorflow, thanks a lot!

Comment: As stupid as it sounds, it works! Let's wait for the support of python3.9+