# Cannot find reference 'handler' in '__init__.py'

Tags: python, aiogram

faced with such an error.

```
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.dispatcher.handler import CancelHandler
from aiogram.dispatcher.middlewares import BaseMiddleware


class AccessMiddleware(BaseMiddleware):
    def __init__(self, access_id: int):
        self.access_id = access_id
        super().__init__()

    async def on_process_message(self, message: types.Message, _):
        if int(message.from_user.id) != int(self.access_id):
            await message.answer("Access Denied")
            raise CancelHandler()
```

`Cannot find reference 'handler' in '__init__.py'`
`Unresolved reference 'CancelHandler'`
`Cannot find reference 'BaseMiddleware' in '__init__.py'`

I tried reinstalling and updating the aiogram library, but it didn't change anything. this is the first time I have encountered such a mistake and I will be glad of any help.

Comment: if you are using pycharm take alook [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23248017/cannot-find-reference-xxx-in-init-py)