# PyCharm - Unresolved library 'staticfiles'

Tags: python, django, pycharm, django-oscar

I'm working on a Django project with PyCharm. Unfortunately PyCharm does not resolve the template tags I would like to use in my templates.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

The project is running within an Ubuntu VM via vagrant. The run configuration knows about the virtualenv I am using in the VM (remote interpreter setup).

My settings look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django_extensions']

INSTALLED_APPS += get_core_apps(['myapp.dashboard')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../../../myfolder/static'),
)
```

Still I get the warning `Unresolved library 'staticfiles'`. It shows the same behavior other template tags as well.
Could the dynamic creation of the `STATICFILES_DIRS` be the issue? How could I solve this?

Comment: This does not solve my question. It is not only about the staticfiles, also about other template tags.

Comment: Are you in DEBUG mode?

Comment: I see no **STATIC_URL**

Comment: Forgot to include it in the post. Edited.

Comment: Reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479696/pycharm-unresolved-reference-error-on-the-ide-when-opening-a-working-project#20479761) content in the second answer it seems Pycharm requires the static content to be included in a folder named static under the application root, but I would also try other solutions mentioned in that question like verify of Pycharm see your project as source

Comment: The things mentioned in the post you recommended are already fulfilled. You only have to put the static folder under the application root, if you did not configure `STATICFILES_DIRS`. All folders, which contain the static files are marked as source.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turned out that the dynamical creation of `INSTALLED_APPS` confuses PyCharm somehow. It cannot resolve certain dependencies such as the `template_tags` if these are created dynamically. Seems like one has to decide whether to have a nice code navigation or static `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: You are right: a simple importing of `INSTALLED_APPS` drives PyCharm crazy.

Comment: I'm currently facing worse: transforming `settings.py` into a module (ie folder names `settings` with `__init__.py` file) and copy/paste old `settings.py` code to another file into the folder `settings` with proper calculation of `BASE_DIR` drives PyCharm totally mad -> you are forced to have all your configuration **only** in one file `settings.py` end of story...

Comment: @OlivierPons Splitting the settings file works fine for me. I have a settings module with __init__.py, base.py, dev.py and prod.py. With the latest PyCharm version 2019, I was able to fix the OP's problem by pointing PyCharm to my dev.py settings file.

Answer (score 29):

In my case this happened when PyCharm couldn't find settings.py file. This because I have - local_setting, prod_setting etc. So I go to File -> Settings -> Language & Framworks -> Django -> Settings and select appropriate file with setting of django project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this setting is already configured for my project.

Comment: This was the problem in my case.

Comment: Don't forget to reload project after pointing to correct settings.py

Comment: This answer should be pointed as the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like PyCharm looks for the last assignment to INSTALLED_APPS to find template tags. I have run into a similar problem and be able to work around it adding this after dynamically generating the real INSTALLED_APPS:

```
if False:
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.sites',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'autocomplete_light',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.humanize',
        'comunes',
        'listados',
        'gescomercial',
        'contabilidad',
        'compras',
        'almacen')
```

Not pretty, but as this settings.py is only used in the development machine I can live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Using PyCharm `2019.2`, once the `settings.py` is correctly pointed to in django preferences config panel I needed to invalidate the cache and restart before Pycharm correctly recognised all templatetags library, even if my `INSTALLED_APPS` is dynamically built.

Answer (score 1):

Lower the Django version. My situation is the same as yours. The configuration in the setting is correct, but still prompts "unresolved Library 'static files'. After that, I lower the Django version. PIP install Django = = 2.1.7. The problem has been solved. I hope it will help you