# pycharm is not showing autocomplete for my own modules

Tags: django, autocomplete, pycharm

I am using pycharm for a django project. I made an app named 'music' and there I created a model named 'Album'.

Inside Views I am using a for loop to get to the details stored in the database like this

```
all_albums = Album.objects.all()
for album in all_albums:
    album.artist
```

however when I type `album.` I don't get autocomplete suggestions for `artist` or anything else that I have defined in that class.

How to make pycharm include my own modules in the autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

One way, using docstrings:

```
for each in qs:
    payment = each
    """@type : Payment """
    print payment.deadline
```

Another way, using assert:

```
for each in qs:
    assert isinstance(each, Payment)
    print each.deadline
```

You can Google 'pycharm type hinting' or similar to find out more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was not looking to set the type manually using either of the both ways.

After reading this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35368305/1641882 I figured that this was the problem with my setup and indeed it was. I set the correct settings file and everything is working.

Thanks for the help though.