# Pycharm doesn't recognize .min.css file (Unresolved template reference) (Django)

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, pycharm

I'm using Django with Pycharm.

I started to use Pycharm Professional today, and Pycharm doesn't recognize my bootstrap.min.css file.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">`
[image: Errors]

I actually have that file in my project folder, but It doesn't appear in Pycharm file tree.
[image: my project folder]
[image: pycharm file tree]

Of course, I've set the static_dir, staticfiles_dirs, and static_root.
[image: django static settings]

This never happened in Pycharm educational version.

thank you

Comment: I think the easiest way to solve this would be to let Pycharm tell you where it thinks the static dir is.
<link ...  href="{% static '<your-cursor-here>' %}" />
Then press the key combination for auto complete. It should show you a directory/list of directories where it thinks the folder is.

Comment: [Pycharm Entry](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html?keymap=secondary_mac_os_x)

Comment: Make sure {% load staticfiles %} is at the top of your template files

Comment: This answered it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679755/pycharm-unresolved-library-staticfiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. You need to change the Pycharm preference.

Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Python Template Languages > 
Template language: Django

[image: pic]

Comment: While we understand that you may be a little excited, please don't use F-words as it may sound offensive to others.

Comment: You can link the picture and someone will edit them in.

Answer (score 2):

settings.py   remove STATIC_ROOT, replace the others like so:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

At the top of your template, before any HTML    {% load static %}

Answer (score 0):

```
put this code in settings.py
IN WINDOW OS

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('C:/Python27/Scripts/yourprojectname/static/'),


IN UBUNTU

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/yourprojectfolderpath/static/'),


AND IN TEMPLATE FILE ON THE TOP

{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

in settings.py

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and then add >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>STATICFILES_DIRS =['PUT THE PATH TO YOUR STATIC FILE HERE(YOUR PROJECT FOLDER WHICH contains IT)/static/']

```
like so
```

```
 STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        "qinasmartmap/static/",
        "qinasmartmap/qinaservics/static/",
    
    ]
```

then add it to

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [STATIC_DIR, ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

don't forget to
`{% load static %}` in your HTML files