# Getting error in importing path and include from django.urls

Tags: python, django

I have created a sample project using Django but when I opened the file in IDE it shows error for importing **path** and **include** from **django.urls** module.

The error statement is `Cannot find reference 'include' in '__init__.py'` and `Cannot find reference 'path' in '__init__.py'`

Comment: What Django version are you using?

Comment: Django 2.2.9 and Python 3.6.9

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479696/pycharm-unresolved-reference-error-on-the-ide-when-opening-a-working-project

Comment: probably your IDE using some other environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If IDE is Pycharm, try to add source directory in File -> Settings -> Project -> Project structure.

Answer (score 1):

you must use manage.py script to run your project in the right way