# Cannot find reference 'get_accounts' in '__init__.py' in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, algorand

I see there are other question like this but none can solve my issue.
I'm trying the Algosdk in PyCharm following the [tutorial](https://github.com/algorand/py-algorand-sdk/blob/examples/examples/account.py#L5-L9) snippet.
But when I try to write it in my PyCharm i get always this error

```
Cannot find reference 'get_accounts' in __init__.py
```

in PyCharm in the first line of this

```
from utils import get_accounts, get_algod_client 
from algosdk import account, mnemonic

accts = get_accounts()
```

The same error appears also in `get_algod_client`

I've followed the path and I've discovered that the `__init__.py` of utils is empty, but I don't know how to fill it, because i downloaded it from the official Algorand website.
I have also imported the the `py-algorand-sdk` in my Project interpreter `(Settings->Project: MyProject-> Python interpreter)` but nothing changed.
Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just tried on a fresh new PyCharm 2023.1.2 project (Python 3.11 with a venv), creating just two files in the project: `main.py` and `utils.py`.
And I do not have the issue.

`main.py`:

```py
from utils import get_accounts, get_algod_client
from algosdk import account, mnemonic
from algosdk import transaction

# example: ACCOUNT_GENERATE
private_key, address = account.generate_account()
print(f"address: {address}")
print(f"private key: {private_key}")
print(f"mnemonic: {mnemonic.from_private_key(private_key)}")
```

`utils.py` from https://github.com/algorand/py-algorand-sdk/blob/79c6ce965391dddc6764d75d8e2f6f11a194a21d/examples/utils.py

It is possible however that if you have an older version that has some issues.

Can you try/check:

1. Check that `utils.py` exists in the same folder and is the one above.
2. Update PyCharm to the latest version?
3. If this does not work and if your sources are in a subfolder, mark the director as "Source root". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479761 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/52390958

You can also check whether the issue is PyCharm-related or not, by running in the console `python3 main.py`.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem re-downloading the utils.py file.
I don't know why but the first download go wrong, now all works.